# Existing SaaS and new mobile app, how to deal with Apple payment options?

Tags: ios, app-store, saas

We run an *existing* B2B SaaS which is a web app (website). *Existing* Customers pay around EUR 150 each per month. As it is a niche market targeting national regulations in my country, the number of potential customers is very limited and we acquire new customers ourselves. Now, we would like to add a mobile app (android, ios) so customers could be allowed to use it off line as it is used in the field.
The mobile app should be free, as it augments the existing subscription to the platform. Installed PWA does not work for this scenario as there is a considerable data store/database involved (so I need SQLite).
IMO the Apple policies do not address this scenario.
We do *not* need the exposure in the app stores (we do the acquisition) and we do *not* need the payment services (already have that). Android sideloading is nice but that does not work on iOS.
I am pretty sure that the policies state we should add options in the app to acquire a subscription from within the app, incurring the 15/30% which would kinda makes sense for *new* customers that found us through the store, but as I said, I find that highly unlikely because of the niche nature of the SaaS. There are *literally* about 500-750 businesses in total that deal with the national regulatory contents covered by the SaaS.
Suddenly paying EUR 50,00 per month for each existing client just to be allowed to install an app on an iOS device is just not a viable option.
Increasing the price to EUR 215 p/m so we still receive the net 150 p/m will not go down well either. It feels like there is no option for us to create a mobile app.
What am I missing here? How do other businesses solve this?

Comment: Just have the app set up to login in to your SaaS service. Do not provide any sign up options for users that haven't already set up their account via your web site and you don't have a problem.  If you want to provide an option for users to sign up within the app then you have to use IAP, but there is no reason that people with an existing subscription need to switch their payment method to IAP

Comment: You might also want to look at [unlisted apps](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/) - you can provide a link to the app from your web site but not have it appear in App Store search results.

Comment: Thanks @paulw11. Sifting through a lot of web FUD and the policies, I had interpreted having just a login as a violation. I will scrutinize the policies again. Both suggestions are interesting BTW

Comment: I work for a startup SaaS provider. Our app works pretty much as I described in my first comment, except you can't sign up on web. We work with enterprises so they go through our sales channel and pay via invoice. Our app is in both Apple and Google stores

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for that addition. This might be an interesting way to go forward.